# Rg.Plugins.Popup nuget package(1.2.0.223) giving crash for Xamarin UWP Project

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have added Rg.Plugins.Popup package latest version 1.2.0.223 for Xamarin Uwp project and Init that PopUp control in App.xaml.cs file of Uwp solution.

Then I have create one Popup page Xaml and called it from Mainpage.xaml.cs file using method,By calling Its giving crash and debugger.Break() has been called.

```
/*App.xaml.cs this file Init Popup Control*/
      protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active
            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
                Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
                Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);

                if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                    //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                }

                // Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }

            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                // parameter
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
            }
            // Ensure the current window is active
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }

    /*PopUp Control Xaml code*/
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
            <pages:PopupPage
            x:Class="ProjectName.DashboardBrush.DashbordDistrictPage"
            xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
            xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
            prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True">
            <StackLayout
                Margin="5,50,0,0"
                Padding="1"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                HeightRequest="420"
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="Start"
                WidthRequest="200">
                <Frame BorderColor="Black">
                    <ListView
                        x:Name="districtListView"
                        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                        ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        RowHeight="50"
                        SeparatorColor="Black"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                        <!--  Built in Cells  -->
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextCell Text="{Binding .}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </pages:PopupPage>


/*Method From which Popup page is calling*/    
    async void FilterOptionClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dashboardFilterView = new DashboardBrushFilter(dashboardViewModel.selectedFilters.ToArray());
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(dashboardFilterView);
        }
```

Comment: Please use `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, Popup.GetExtraAssemblies());` to replace `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);` and try again, here is my sample, I don't have any issue:https://github.com/CherryBu/Popupsample

Comment: I have solved it by removing  RowHeight="50" tag from listview,because  RowHeight was not working in windows UWP. After removing that Popup worked fine.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue now, please give one reply to share your solution, it is beneficial to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have changed in PopUp page Xaml. I have removed "RowHeight = 50" line from it because it was not working in windows uwp.

Comment: If you still have some issue, please provide one sample at github that can reproduce your issue,I will help you to test, because I have no issue, you can take my sample:https://github.com/CherryBu/Popupsample

Comment: are you sure that this is related to RowHeight? i am seeing this crash for without ListView popups as well.